# use Java to convert ANY file to hex and back again

Tags: java

I have some files i would like to convert to hex, alter, and then reverse again, but i have a problem trying to  do jars, zips, and rars. It seems to only work on files containing normally readable text. I have looked all around but cant find anything that would allow jars or bats to do this correctly. Does anyone have an answer that does both? converts to hex then back again, not just to hex?

Comment: Is "Is it impossible to convert certain files to hex?" your entire question?

Comment: @immibis no it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert any file to hex. It's just a matter of obtaining a byte stream, and mapping every byte to two hexadecimal numbers.

Here's a utility class that lets you convert from a binary stream to a hex stream and back:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Hex {
    public static void binaryToHex(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

        try {
            int value;

            while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
                writer.write(String.format("%02X", value));
            }

            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("An error occurred");
        }
    }

    public static void hexToBinary(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            char buffer[] = new char[2];

            while (reader.read(buffer) != -1) {
                os.write((Character.digit(buffer[0], 16) << 4)
                        + Character.digit(buffer[1], 16));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("An error occurred");
        }
    }
}
```

Partly inspired by [this sample from Mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-file-to-hex-in-java/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/3558960).

Comment: This is correct. +1... But note that you will corrupt almost all non-text files by altering random bytes.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen this code i have tried but enter was converted to .. and this doesn't help me convert it back.

Comment: @Robby, the OP wants to convert to hex, **alter** and convert it back.

Comment: @Moocow9m The example code has hex and text output. You only need the hex output.

Comment: @Codebender I would not be doing it by random.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it doesn't convert it back... I need it to convert back on command.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen how do i get rid of the original text in the output?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it seems on conversion back i get an exception...http://prntscr.com/886l51

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87733/discussion-between-moocow9m-and-robby-cornelissen).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `Reader` to read `String` / `char` / `char[]`, use an `InputStream` to read `byte` / `byte[]`.